# What is the best way to add additional input field on a button click?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-redux

I am wondering what is the standard way to add additional input field from onClick() on a button. **A scenario might be adding a Todo-list item field on click.**

My approach was having a state array that stores the actual component and concat the array.

```
const[ComponentList, setComponentList] = useState([<Component id={1}/>]);
```

And then...

```
function addAnotherQuestion() {
    setComponentList(ComponentList.concat(generateComponent(currentID)));
 }
```

I was told this is a very bad idea and I would end up with messed up inputs because of stale states (which I did, and then I solved by writing to Redux store directly from the child component). This is not an ideal solution, so I want to know what is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store only inputs data in array like so:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(["some_id_1", "some_id_2", "some_id_3"]);
```

```
function addAnotherQuestion() {
    setInputs(inputs.concat(currentID));
}
```

and then render them separately:

```
<>
 { inputs.map((id) => <Component key={id} id={id}/>) }
</>
```

Comment: I refractored my code to be similar to this. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping an array of Id's instead of components?

```
const[ComponentListIds, setComponentListIds] = useState([1]);
```

Why do you need to generate the components? What you should probably do, is generating new Id's instead. And then render the components within the render part of you component with:

```
render(
...
ComponentListIds.map(id=> <Component key={id} id={id}>)
...
)
```

Comment: The components is an input field, and it is generated when the user clicks on a button. Think To do app. The user would click on a "add to do item" button and a new todo input component would be added.